# How to load custom font for a target div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, fonts

**Problem**: I am having a textfield(with class "textTochange") where I can enter some texts and then I am having a select field(with class "fontCustom") which holds a list of custom fonts.(All the font files with  .ttf format are stored in a directory called "myFonts") And there is a div(with class "textToDisplay") which will display the entered text by loading the custom font-family selected.

**Markup**:

```
    <input type="text" class="textToChange" />

    <select class="fontCustom">
      <option value="customfontfilename.ttf">Custom Font File Name</option>
      <option value="customfontfilename.ttf">Custom Font File Name</option>
      <option value="customfontfilename.ttf">Custom Font File Name</option>
     </select>

    <div class="textToDisplay">
    </div>
```

**Expected Solution**:

I am expecting a solution that will show the entered text using the custom font files from my directory(not from google fonts) with the help of jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would approach this:

1. Include all the webfonts in their own css file. (e.g. font_1.css, font_2.css...)
2. Create a class for every webfont
3. Listen to the change event on the select field to get the selected font
   `$('select').on('change', function() {
       var fontToLoad = $(this).val();
   });`
4. Load required css file `$('head').append(pathToCSS);`
5. Add css class `$('.textToDisplay').addClass('myFontClass');`